# clickOnButton not works in Nexus one

Tags: android, robotium

I am using robotium3.3 for my test project.I am testing it in **Nexus one** device.it was working fine untill i updated the **device OS**.last day i got a system update alert and i updated my device. After that i could **not** run robotium in that device.When it is executing button click event it is throwing **null pointer exception**. In another devices I could run the test project. What should i do to make it work in Nexus one devcie?

Comment: Also post errors from logcat

Comment: if it is an error in code then how it is working in other devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different Os versions require different code from robotium sometimes because internally robotium uses reflection to get hold of certain information. I assume you got an update to 4.2 which requires robotium 3.6 as a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Robotium supports android 4.2 since version 3.6

> "Robotium 3.6 is better then ever. Now with full support for Android 4.2!"